# HTML input pattern for alphanumeric, underscore, dash and dot

Tags: html, regex

I wanted to form pattern in HTML input field, which can have only below allowed chars:

- alfanumeric (a-zA-Z0-9)
- underscore (_)
- dash (-)
- dot (.)

I am trying `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_-\.]"` but it is not working. Not sure why. How I can do it?

Some valid example input:

- aA12_-.
- Aasdj
- 123123
- _Afsdf.
- _end.1

Comment: You can use `required`.

Comment: I recommend reading this: https://www.troyhunt.com/security-insanity-how-we-keep-failing-at-the-basics/

Comment: Because of the hyphen, this part of the expression, ``_-\``, represents a range of all the characters that sort between underscore and backslash.  When inside brackets, if a hyphen isn't supposed to have this special meaning, it must be the first or last character.

Answer (score 4):

Your pattern matches only a single character. If you want to match multiple characters including zero append *, for at least one character append + e.g.

```
<input pattern="[-a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+" />
```

read more at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: In addition the `-` denotes a *range* when used in the middle. When using the original pattern in Perl, I got: `Invalid [] range "_-\." in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/[a-zA-Z0-9_-\. <-- HERE ]/`

Comment: @U.Windl - that's what led me here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
/^[\w\._-]+$/
```

**Note:**

1. Use `-` at the end or start of the bracket.  Using is at the start may keep the semantics when adding mire characters before the end of the bracket group.
2. You are not allowed to use the space Between words.(if you want space between words insert space inside bracket like this : `/^[\w\._ -]+$/`)

```js
patt = /^[\w\._-]+$/;

function test(){
  var v = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  v = v.trim();
  console.log(patt.test(v));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt"> 
<button onclick="test()">test</button>
```

Comment: `_` is already included in `\w` and there're no needs to escape the dot in a character class.

Comment: Putting the - at the end of the bracket fixed my regex thank you - if it was anywhere else Chrome refused to do the validation